# How to handle multiple input with same name and store it in Database

Tags: php, arrays, database, http-post

I have a form which has 5 input field with name-

```
style[]
color[]
quantity[]
price[]
description[]
```

Now the thing is these input fields can be cloned.

after posting data it looks like

```
[style] => Array
    (
        [0] => km210
        [1] => km230
    )

[color] => Array
    (
        [0] => black
        [1] => blue
    )

[quantity] => Array
    (
        [0] => 100
        [1] => 200
    )

[price] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1000
        [1] => 2000
    )

[description] => Array
    (
        [0] => Extended shoulder
        [1] => Crochet
    )
```

How can i properly store this data into database and count how many color was input and how many style was added

In sql database their are 5 fields

```
id
style
color
quantity
price
description
```

Comment: You have to provide more details. What does your schema look like? What entity those styles and colors belong to? What is the scenario you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Since they are all arrays then it is a matter of looping over each indice, building and executing the appropriate sql statement.